# Required radio button does not validate in form, when clicked through Javascript/jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript, forms, validation, radio

I have a radio button that selects a dealer in my checkout. I need this button to automatically be checked for the user - however, no matter what I do, the radio button still needs to be clicked to validate.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
document.getElementById("#dealer-selection-" + elm.id).click();
```

This makes the radio button show up as if it's been clicked, however when submitting form, a notice still pops up with a validation error.

```
jQuery('.forhandlerRadio:first').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Same thing as above - this shows the radio button as clicked, but for the purposes of the submit button, it is not.

```
jQuery("#dealer-selection-" + elm.id).trigger("click",function(){
                selectDealer(jQuery(this).val());
            });
```

Again, this shows the button as clicked, but it is not.

I have even tried simply adding `checked="CHECKED"` to the radio button itself, which also shows as checked, but does not validate.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871063/how-to-set-radio-option-checked-onload-with-jquery

Comment: Thank you, however I already found a different solution. I appreciate the quick help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found one that works for me:

```
document.getElementById("#dealer-selection-" + elm.id).checked=true;
```

For some reason, this one checks the radio button visually, while also checking it as an option.